# Online/offline статус пользователей в режиме реального времени

Tags: java, websocket, realtime

У нас в компании есть внутренний проект, на котором мы обучаемся в свободное время от основных проектов. Проект — мессенджер с функцией видеосвязи. Видеосвязь и месседжинг (возможность создавать и общаться в общих каналах) мы берём из стороннего SDK.

Клиентское приложение написано нативно под iOS и Android. Бэкенд на джаве.

В приложении есть стандартный список контактов. И сейчас появилась задача, отслеживать в режиме реального времени статус пользователя (в идеале, имплементировать функционал как в телеграме, типа "был в сети 5 часов назад") в списке контактов, и по заходу на его профиль.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть? Что нужно сделать на сервере, и что на клиенте?

После часов гугления, я узнал, что существует такая технология как websocket, и такой инструмент как kafka. Можно ли это как-то связать?

Comment: В стороннем SDK нет такого функционала?

Comment: Не могу ответить в комментариях из-за репутации, поэтому напишу здесь. Glebka — к сожалению нет, или возможно я что-то упускаю. SDK это от Amazon Chime. ЮрийСПб — хорошо, спасибо, я понял. Когда напишу какое-то решение, запощу его сюда. Если вкратце, то есть идея по вебсокету сообщать слушателям об изменениях в таблице, которая будет отвечать за активность пользователей

Comment: Вот нашел что-то похожее:
Получаем аккаунты: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccounts.html
и в ответе смотрим AccountStatus

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать сильно по разному, в зависимости от желаемого набора фич.

Но, в основе своей вам надо реализовать следующее:

1. Способ определения когда юзер активен.
2. Способ получения статуса активен/неактивен

---

Простейший способ, без сокетов будет такой:

1. Когда юзер совершает какое-то действие, требующее соединения с сервером, на сервере, при поступлении запроса от юзера записывается время прихода запроса.
2. Теперь, запрашивая с сервера инфу о к-л юзере вы можете отдавать и записанное в п1 время.

Такое реализовать максимально просто. Однако так вы не будете иметь статуса "активен прямо сейчас", если не определять "сейчас" как `прошло не более n времени с последнего обращения юзера к серверу`. Т.е. если юзер просто запустил приложение и смотрит часами на список чатов, не делая сетевых запросов он может быть воспринят как "неактивный"

---

Более сложный способ - постоянно уведомлять сервер о статусе юзера. Например - каждые n времени отправлять на сервер запрос пока приложение запущено. Это можно и обычными запросами делать или да, сокет соединение поддерживая, что может быть в ряде случаев предпочтительнее в смысле кол-ва запросов на сервер.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Рассмотрим первый вариант, как один из возможных.

Не могли бы вы расписать про второй вариант в двух словах, как бы вы это реализовывали?


Насколько я знаю, в веб-сокетах есть такая "вещь" как топики. И насколько я понимаю, сервер должен создавать топик для каждого подключённого юзера, и туда принимать сообщения об изменениях статуса, и рассылать его всем слушателям

Comment: В двух словах, наверное, не получится... Топики тут тоже, по идее, не подойдут, к тому же я не уверен, что они в WebSocket есть, скорее в отдельных протоколах. В зависимости от того как у вас сервер реализован и как там хранятся данные можно получать уведомления об изменениях в записях в активности юзеров (триггерами на уровне БД, если они есть в вашей БД или механизмами фреймфорка (в спринге, вроде, есть что-то такое)). Эти уведомления можно транслировать клиенту по сокету. По идее, при этом клиент должен на сервер список ID юезров для отслеживания передать.

Answer (score 0):

В общем получилось решить следующим образом:

1. В базе данных создаётся таблица user_activity (user_id, status, last_seen);
2. Для этой таблицы создаётся функция-триггер, которая рассылает уведомления об изменениях в этой таблице;
3. В коде создаётся слушатель этих самых уведомлений (событий);
4. Каждый клиент во время подключения к веб-сокету передаёт свой id/username на веб-сокет контролер;
5. Каждый раз, когда приходит обновление из соответствующей таблицы (users_activity), мы делаем:

- достаём у каждого подключённого клиента список его контактов;
- смотрим у кого в контактах есть пользователь, по которому пришло обновление с базы данных, и отправляем клиенту по веб-сокету соответствующий JSON, например

```json
{    
    "username" : "username",    
    "status" : "online",   
    "last_seen" : 1152359098263742 
}
```

Как вам такое решение?

P.S. Объясните пожалуйста, почему у меня в ТС-посте показывает 51 рейтинг, а в профиле 1? Я невероятно туплю...

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin благодарю!